# Совместное использование сайтов на разных вебсерверах в разных ОС

Tags: windows, ubuntu, apache, веб-сервер, openserver

Здравствуйте. На компьютере на 2-х разных дисках установлены Windows 10 и Ubuntu 16.04 (Для работы так нужно). На Windows установлен Openserver (файловая система NTFS), На Ubuntu - чистый Apache, PHP, Mysql.

Есть сайт, который нормально работает на Windows. Нужно чтобы была возможность запустить его и в Ubuntu (В Mysql установлена копия базы данных). Из самой Ubuntu доступ к файлам есть, права 777. Прописал в настройках Apache2 виртуальный хост с указанием нужного пути - проверяю работу - ошибка 403 апача, не сайта!

**UPD.** Нашел подобную проблему [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163685/403-forbidden-error-in-apache-with-document-root-on-an-ntfs-partition). У меня сам диск называется **info**, после монтирования диска путь получается "/media/alex/info/Openserver/domains". Сам путь рабочий - ввожу "cd "/media/alex/info/Openserver/domains" - папка открывается. Прописал этот путь в Apache2.conf и настройки сайта по умолчанию... проблема та же..

Сделал

```
sudo umount /dev/sda4
mkdir /media/webmaster
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /media/webmaster
```

Исправил пути на "/media/webmaster/Openserver/domains", сделал рестарт апача - ситуация не поменялась... Хотя когда открываю в Noatilus пишет название диска webmaster.

Подскажите, как правильно это настроить? Если будет возможность ещё и базу сделать общей, это будет очень хорошо.

**UPD.** Ещё выполнил

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/webmaster
```

всё заработало. Осталось ещё общую базу сделать...